# Applications of $L_p$ spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, applications

I'm studying Lebesgue integration theory and understand the definition of $L_p$ spaces.

What can we do with $L_p$ spaces?

Comment: This might interest you: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28147/why-do-we-care-about-lp-spaces-besides-p-1-p-2-and-p-infty

Comment: for applications of functional analysis, there is already a popular question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556307/what-are-the-applications-of-functional-analysis